# create-react-app typescript re-compile issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have a React project with TypeScript which is bootstrapped with create-react-app. I am using a separate file with **.ts** extension to declare types and interfaces. It looks like below.

```
export type TextFieldProps = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  label: string;
};
```

My problem is if I change the type the compiler is not recompiling. If I change any other file it is working. I am expecting a solution without ejecting and adding config to the webpack manually. Can anyone help me to solve this without ejecting? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean with _if I change the type the compiler is not recompiling_ ?

Comment: I have a file where the TypeScript types are declared and this is imported to the component file and being used. Now if I change something in the Type file the compiler is not recompiling the application and nothing happened in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Two options that I can see:

1) Make your own watch task (with gulp, for example), which updates the web-page by running "npm run build".

2) Override create-react-app web-pack-config. Haven't done this myself, but I know that people do. This example looks promising: https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc